# Keras tensorflow maxpool layer destroying accuracy VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code for training and testing MNIST data. I am building up to VGG16. I have a high 90's accuracy until I add the MaxPool2D layer at which point it goes to 11% accuracy. I have tried adding another Dense layer and it did not fix the issue. How to get the MaxPool2D to not destroy accuracy?

edit: I am building the network piece by piece since implementing VGG16 also resulted in accuracy of 11%, and I want to figure out at which point it all comes apart (comments on if this is incorrect?). It seems that it falls apart as soon as I added that MaxPool2D layer

edit: I have increased accuracy by adding a padding=same and removing the second layer input shape, but now the accuracy is low when I add another conv2d layer..

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    # Load the input data
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
    x_train = x_train[..., tf.newaxis]
    x_test = x_test[..., tf.newaxis]

    # Build the model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding=""same, input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=""same, activation='relu'),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2) padding=""same,),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=""same, activation='relu'),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    checkpoint_path = "./training_1/cp.ckpt"
    # Create a callback instance that saves the model's weights
    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                     save_weights_only=True,
                                                     verbose=0)

    # Training the model with given data
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5, callbacks=[cp_callback])


    # model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)

    model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5, callbacks=[cp_callback])
    model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
```

Comment: What happens if you set the pooling layers strides to None? Using VGG aside, since you have an input shape of 28, max pooling with the same stride will destroy much of the information in the output from the convolutional layers. 

I would try to not use MaxPooling but instead AveragePooling2D.
Also you probably only need to specify the input_shape in the first layer.

Comment: I kept maxpooling but added padding="same", and removed the input shape from the second layer. However I once again lose accuracy when adding a new Conv2D layer

Comment: Try giving model.summary() and look at the output shapes of the data after each layer. Maybe using the MaxPool layer takes away a lot of data, or in other words, significantly reduces the dimension of the data that it is difficult for the model to train properly.